# How to remove duplicate values from a table

Tags: sql

I'm working on pulling data to a table which has two data sets of data loaded to temp table and finally inserts into table. There are 2 records which are duplicates but i need both the records if their value on one column is same else delete it. Col1 and col4 are primary keys

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
--------------------
a     ab   abc  x
a     ab   abc  y
b     ab   abc  y
b     ab   abc  z
```

what i want is forget about col 2 and col3, check in col1 if row 1 and row 2 are same it should go check col4 and if row1 and row 2 are different it should display both row1 and row 2 even if row 2 and row 3 in col4 are same. so if the records are as i mentioned it should allow all 4 values but with the logic i wrote it is returning row1,row3,row4 because it is considering row2 and row3 of col 1  with row 2 row 3 of col 4 and displaying only 3 records but i want all records. Please help me how to write a logic in sql for this situation.

Comment: To be clear, you have a 4 column primary key?! I'd suggest a follow on question about the design of this table.

Comment: col 1 and col 4 are primary keys

Comment: please, add the desired result

Comment: I'm having a very hard time following the logic. Could you put in the result you want? Also, please show us what you've tried.

Comment: select  row_number() over partition by col4 orderby col3 as rownum,col1,col2,col3,col4 from temptable group by col1,col2,col3,col4 where rownum=1 .                                                                                              is the logic i tried to insert data from temp table but this logic is loadind only 3 records. i want all the four row i mentioned in the table

Comment: it should display all records as in the table even though it has primary key. It should only delete a record if col1 and col4 for any 2 rows are same

Comment: @Gee : show us success and failure cases.

Comment: @Gee : If col1 and col4 are same, which record should it delete? should it delete both?

Comment: if row1 and row 2 of col1 and col4 are same then delete one record else display both records.

Comment: @Gee: Which record should it leave from duplicate records? first or second or third...? there must be some criteria.

Comment: @Gee You keep referring to "row1" and "row2", and this is a problem. SQL databases lack an implied order, so this doesn't make much sense. Maybe you're referring to the rows in your example, but it's confusing. Instead, you have to think of it in terms of the values in those columns. Like "all rows where col1 is the same".

Comment: Thanks all.. I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have understood from your question, you could do something like this..

```
DELETE i
FROM YourTable i INNER JOIN
( 
SELECT col1,col4 
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY col1,col4
HAVING count(col2)>1
) t ON t.col1 = i.col1 AND t.col4 = i.col4
```

[**Live Demo Here**](http://rextester.com/WKX62394)

Or if ou want to keep only one record and remove other duplicate records, you could do like this..

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by col1,col4 order by col1,col4) as rn
    FROM YourTable
)

DELETE from cte where rn>1
```

[**Live Demo Here**](http://rextester.com/ABLY14662)